# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, scala, serialization, apache-spark

Hello

I am using **Scala 2.11.8 and spark 1.6.1**. whenever I call function inside **map**, it throws the following exception:

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable"
```

You can find below my full code

```
package moviestream.recommender
import java.io
import java.io.Serializable

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
import org.jblas.DoubleMatrix


class FeatureExtraction{

  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Recommendation")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val rawData = sc.textFile("data/u.data")
  val rawRatings = rawData.map(_.split("\t").take(3))

  //create rating object from rawratings
  val ratings = rawRatings.map{case Array(user,movie,rating) => Rating(user.toInt,movie.toInt,rating.toDouble)}
  //user Spark ALS library to train our model
  // Build the recommendation model using ALS

  val model = ALS.train(ratings,50,10,0.01)
  //val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings,50,10,0.01,0.1) //last parameter is alpha
  val predictedRating = model.predict(789,123)
  //top ten recommended movies for user id 789, where k= number of recommended(10) 789=userid
  val topKRecs = model.recommendProducts(789,10)
  val movies = sc.textFile("data/u.item")
  val titles = movies.map(line=>line.split("\\|").take(2)).map(array=>(array(0).toInt,array(1))).collectAsMap()
  //how many    movies  this    user    has rated
  val moviesForUser = ratings.keyBy(_.user).lookup(789)
  //we  will    take    the 10  movies  with    the highest ratings ction   using   the     field   of  the     object.
  //moviesForUser.sortBy(-_.rating).take(10).map(rating=>(titles(rating.product),rating.rating)).foreach(println)
  //let’s   take    a   look    at  the top 10  recommendations for this    user    and see what    the titles
  //topKRecs.map(rating=>(titles(rating.product),rating.rating)).foreach(println)
  //    we  will    then    need    to  create  a   DoubleMatrix    object

  val itemId = 567
  val itemFactor = model.productFeatures.lookup(itemId).head
  val itemVector = new  DoubleMatrix(itemFactor)


  //we  are ready   to  apply   our similarity  metric  to  each    item
  /*val sims = model.productFeatures.map{ case (id, factor) =>
    val factorVector = new DoubleMatrix(factor)
    val sim = cosineSimilarity(factorVector, itemVector)
    (id, sim)
  }*/

  //we can  compute the top 10  most    similar items   by  sorting out the similarity  score   for each    item
  //val sortedSims = sims.top(10)(Ordering.by[(Int,Double),Double]{case(id,similarity)=>similarity})

  //we  can sense   check   our item-to-item    similarity
  //val sortedSims2 = sims.top(11)(Ordering.by[(Int,Double),Double]{case(id,similarity)=>simintellij idea debugilarity})
  //sortedSims2.slice(1,11).map{case (id,sim)=>(titles(id),sim)}.foreach(println)
  //Finally,we  can print   the 10  items   with    the highest computed    similarity  metric  to  our given item:
  //println("Result = "+titles(123))

  def cosineSimilarity(vect1:DoubleMatrix,vect2:DoubleMatrix): Double = {
    vect1.dot(vect2)/(vect1.norm1()*vect2.norm2())
  }

  val actualRating = moviesForUser.take(1)(0)
  val predictedRatings = model.predict(789,actualRating.product)
  //println(predictedRatings)
  val squaredError = math.pow(predictedRatings - actualRating.rating,2.0)

  val usersProducts = ratings.map{case Rating(user,product,rating) => (user,product)}
  val predictions = model.predict(usersProducts).map{case Rating(user,product,rating)
                          =>((user,product),rating)}
  val ratingsAndPredictions = ratings.map{case Rating(user,product,rating)=>((user,product),rating)}
                                     .join(predictions)
  val MSE = ratingsAndPredictions.map{case ((user,product),(actual,predicted))
          => math.pow((actual-predicted),2)}.reduce(_ + _)/ratingsAndPredictions.count()
  //println("Mean Squared Error = " + MSE)
  val RMSE = math.sqrt(MSE)
  println("Root Mean Squared Error = "+ RMSE)
  def avgPrecisionK(actual:Seq[Int],predicted:Seq[Int],k:Int):Double = {
    val predk = predicted.take(k)
    var score = 0.0
    var numHits = 0.0
    for((p,i)<- predk.zipWithIndex){
      if(actual.contains(p)){
        numHits += 1.0
        score += numHits/(i.toDouble+1.0)
      }
    }
    if(actual.isEmpty) {
      1.0
    }
    else{
      score/scala.math.min(actual.size,k).toDouble
    }


  }

  val actualMovies = moviesForUser.map(_.product)
  val predictedMovies = topKRecs.map(_.product)
 //predictedMovies.foreach(println)
  val apk10 = avgPrecisionK(actualMovies,predictedMovies,10)
  //println(apk10)
  //Locality Sensitive Hashing
  val itemFactors = model.productFeatures.map{case (id,factor)=>factor}.collect()
  val itemMatrix = new  DoubleMatrix(itemFactors)
  //println(itemMatrix.rows,itemMatrix.columns)
  val imBroadcast = sc.broadcast(itemMatrix)
  //println(imBroadcast)
  val allRecs = model.userFeatures.map{case (userId,array)=>
                val userVector = new  DoubleMatrix(array)
                val scores = imBroadcast.value.mmul(userVector)
                val sortedWithId = scores.data.zipWithIndex.sortBy(- _._1)
                val recommendedIds = sortedWithId.map(_._2 +1).toSeq
                (userId,recommendedIds)
  }
  println(allRecs)


}
```

Comment: Putting code snippets is cool but this is missing the model creation, etc. The error message is generic considering the context. No action were triggered on allRecs. Spark is lazy. *Conclusion : This question is off-topic for many reasons*.

Comment: ^ agree with @eliasah. Note also that Spark 1.6 needs to be manually compiled for scala 2.11. You will be able to unit test this ok, but you will not be able to deploy on a cluster unless you have a manually compiled version of spark.

Comment: @Humayoo could you give more details on the class that is contained by the RDD you get doing model.userFeatures?

Comment: @mauriciojost it looks like MatrixFactorizationModel. Nevertheless even with this information, the question is quite broad.

Comment: i added full code.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments above, the question is too broad. But one guess could help. You use inside `map` the broadcasted value `imBroadcast`. I guess it includes functions declared in the same scope as sparkContext, right? Move them to separate object then.